# Starteam will not check-in a new file added to a project

Tags: .net, version-control, starteam

I am using Visual Studio 2005 and StarTeam 2008 (cross-platform client and VS integration). At some point, I added an 'App.config' to a project. I notice now that this file will not check-in.

1. The 'StarTeam Pending Checkins' window in VS reports the file 'Not in View'. Selecting it for check in and clicking 'Check In Files' causes a dialog to appear - 'Any operation... requires completing the pending renames/deletes'. I click 'Yes' to proceed and nothing happens.
2. The StarTeam client reports this file as 'Modified'. If I check-in from the client, I get no 'complete pending renames/deletes' dialog and the file quickly appears with a 'Current' status.
3. Refreshing StarTeam from VS, I still see the file as 'Not in View'.

I have tried forcing the check-in. I completely removed my working files and pulled the solution fresh in hopes that the StarTeam status ('Current') would apply in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I solved this...

1. I had a co-worker with better credentials add the file to the same project.
2. He checked in successfully.
3. I blew away my working files and pulled the solution from Visual Studio.
4. I added the content to the file, saw the modified status, and checked in.

It appears that normal users do not have delete privileges (just regular delete, not permanent history erasing delete). And in some cases the pending delete cycle (is that managed by StarTeam?) doesn't execute and you can't check in files.

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting the file to just start over.

1. I deleted it from the project in VS and StarTeam client (deleting working files too).
2. I can partially check-in... the 'StarTeam Pending Checkins' window in VS reports the status as 'Locally deleted'
3. I can't find out how to complete the 'pending delete' (I'm assuming this is the requirement).

There are no traces of the file in the StarTeam client... and I can't find any pending rename/delete information. I cannot force the check-in in VS any further.

Answer (score 0):

I am not specialist of StarTeam, but this behavior could be consistent with a file already managed by a Windows process, which would prevent StarTeam to do its checkin operations.

If by checkin StarTeam must temporally move the file and rewrite it, that can be a reason of conflict with the Windows process which will block any write operations on that file.

A possible check would be to close Visual Studio (and all other non-StarTeam program, just to be sure) and try then  to add this file alone.